# Data structures being used in MongoDB (B-Trees etc)

Tags: mongodb

Assume I am going to insert the following 5 elements in a Mongo db:

```
{id= 1, name=Bob, age=34}
{id= 2, name=Jane, age=22}
{id= 3, name=Mike, age=44}
{id= 4, name=Sam, age=55}
{id= 5, name=Joe, age=21}
```

**1)**
What data structure are these 5 objects stored in (before building an index)?

**2)**
I now build an index based on *age* field. As I understand a B-Tree will now be created containing those 5 objects. But what happens with the *previous* data structure are they still located in that as well?

Comment: It's converted to [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) driverside and is [compressed B+tree](https://source.wiredtiger.com/3.0.0/tune_page_size_and_comp.html) on storage level. There is no "previous" data structure. Index is a separate (smaller) data structure which contains references to the "previous" (I guess you mean "full") data.

Comment: Ok so the initial underlying data structure is also a B-tree (before creating any indices) if I read you comment correctly. Out of curiosity what key is used when storing the (5 in my original example) BSON elements initially in the compressed B-tree (before creating the index manually)?

Comment: In your example the driver adds [_id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) field.

Comment: Ok so basically the only difference between inserting into "initial" data structure and creating your own index is that when you create your own index you can select the key?

Comment: You can create as many indexes as you need yet driver will add the _id field anyway, index collection by this field and use it as a primary key. What exactly are you asking?